# Plone 4: send email when user info is updated

Tags: email, event-handling, plone

I am attempting to add an event listener to a custom product so that I can send an email when the @@personal-information page is saved.

I tried putting the following in my configure.zcml:

```
<subscriber
    for="Products.PluggableAuthService.interfaces.events.IPropertiesUpdatedEvent"
    handler=".handlers.userupdate"
    />
```

And then in my handlers.py:

```
def userupdate(event):
""" Handler for User Properties Updated """
... code to send email...
```

I'm not receiving any errors, but nothing happens. Is that not the right event to listen for? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right approach and your code looks fine to me. Try to set a pdb-statement into your userupdate method and start your instance in the foreground ("bin/instance fg") to see if the code is called when you edit the personal information of a user:

```
def userupdate(event):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

If the method is not called at all, then this might be a bug. Probably this one:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/zope-pas/+bug/795086

Try to use a more recent version of Products.PluggableAuthService in which this bug has been fixed.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PluggableAuthService

According to the release notes using Products.PluggableAuthService 1.7.6 should do the trick.